# Jenkins reports "node low disk space", when will it sync the state of nodes?

Tags: jenkins, tdengine

Jenkins reports "node low disk space", when will it sync the state of nodes?
Even if I released the space on the node, it still reported "node low disk space", and the node was offline.
How to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This does not help you, but I do have the same question. I installed the Mail Watcher plugin to get notifications about nodes going offline and back online and tried to trigger this by forcing low diskspace and cleaning up space on one of the nodes. If I wait more than 1 hour I still get no notification. The only way to force this, is to refresh the status on the "**Manage nodes and clouds**" page of Jenkins. But there must be some auto-refresh or periodic check without viewing this page manually I presume. Could it be a configuration option that has not been found yet?